# NativeScript Typescript: JSON Array to Typescript Typed Array

Tags: json, typescript, nativescript

I need your help, I'm learning NativeScript, here I read the txt file which has JSON data below output. After I fetch them I want to assign it to Array countries. But no luck :(

public countries: Array

console.log(response)

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)))

Output:

[
    {
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "code": "AF"
    },
    {
        "name": "Albania",
        "code": "AL"
    }
]

Please help.
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an `Array<any>`:

`[ { "name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF" }, { "name": "Albania", "code": "AL" } ]`

You need to convert it to a `Array<Country>`, Example:

`result.forEach((e) => { countries.push(new Country(e.name, e.code))`

That, or you can change the return of the function that reads the txt to `Array<Country>`

Comment: Thanks buddy, surprisingly foreach was given error finally solved as above.

Answer (score 1):

finally got it via below code...

```
                    let elements: Array<Country> = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))
                    .map((item:Country) => 
                    {
                        console.log(item.name +  ' < - >' + item.code);
                    })
```

Thanks All :)

Comment: That is working fine in one condition the JSON OUTPUT elements labels, in this case: name and code  [ { "name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF" }, { "name": "Albania", "code": "AL" } ] TO BE THE SAME like the object, in this case Country, properties names

Comment: One more thing, do you try to print-out the elements array variable, console.log(elements)? 
In my case the result was: [undefined, undefined]. 
Any clue why?